# pick first item of repeated in rxjs

Tags: javascript, sockets, filter, merge, rxjs

I am receiving a bunch of streams from socket and want to merge repeated streams into one stream (or pick the first item)

In summary I want do this by rxjs:

```
In:  1 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3
Out: 1 - - - - - 2 - - - 3 - - - 1 - - - - - 2 - - - - - 1 - 2 - - - 3 - -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[distinctUntilChanged](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged) does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var arr = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,3];
for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    if (arr[i]==arr[i-1]){ arr.splice(i,1);i--;}
}
```

OUT : `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses the [`Array.fitler()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) function:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,3].filter((value, index, src) => {
  if(index === 0) {
    //The first element of the array is always included
    return true;
  }
  // Return true (keep) if the current element `value` is different
  // than the element that was last encountered (`src[index-1]`)
  return src[index-1] !== value;
});
```

The output to this is:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

This works by iterating over the array and checking if each element is the same or different than the on that precedes it.  Here is the same thing but as a one liner:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,3].filter((value, index, src) => {
  return index === 0 || src[index-1] !== value;
});
```